# Struct returns indexed numbers and property names

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, mapping, struct

I'm using ethers and hardhat to run my React application. I want to pass an object as a parameter to a Solidity function. The function should map the object (struct) to the id provided as a property in the object.

The following is my Solidity (^0.8.9) code:

```
 struct Mushroom {
    uint256 id;
    uint32 spores;
    string backgroundColor;
    string head;
    string eyes;
    string mouth;
    string element;
    string weapon;
    string armor;
    string accessory;
    uint256 level;
}

mapping(uint256 => Mushroom) public mushroomAttributes;
```

The struct is outside of the contract. Here is the Solidity function I am using to set the mapping.

```
function setMushroomData(Mushroom memory mushroom)
    external
    onlyRole(UPDATER_ROLE)
{
    mushroomAttributes[mushroom.id] = mushroom;
}
```

Here is the data that I am passing to the contract:

```
const data = {
  id: 1,
  spores: 0,
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  head: "round",
  eyes: "Wide",
  mouth: "Open",
  element: "Fire",
  weapon: "Axe",
  armor: "None",
  accessory: "Necklace",
  level: 3
};

const setData = await metadataContract.setMushroomData(data);
await setData.wait();
console.log("setDataTxn: ", setData);
```

I call the public mapping to get the returned details:

```
const attributes = await metadataContract.mushroomAttributes(1);
console.log("attributes: ", attributes);
```

This technically works well, however I am receiving the data with indexed integer values and the string property names like so:

```
[
0: BigNumber {_hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true},
1: 0,
2: "blue",
3: "round",
4: "Wide",
5: "Open",
6: "Fire",
7: "Axe",
8: "None",
9: "Necklace",
10: BigNumber {_hex: '0x03', _isBigNumber: true},
accessory: "Necklace",
armor: "None",
backgroundColor: "blue",
element: "Fire",
eyes: "Wide",
head: "round",
id: BigNumber {_hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true},
level: BigNumber {_hex: '0x03', _isBigNumber: true},
mouth: "Open",
spores: 0,
weapon: "Axe"
]
```

I would like to have this data, but without the indexed values (0,1,2,3,4 etc.). Only the string properties (accessory, id, weapon, armor, etc.) are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. According to the Ethers documentation regarding calling a read-only method of a contract:

> The type of the result depends on the ABI. If the method returns a single value, it will be returned directly, otherwise a Result object will be returned with each parameter available positionally and if the parameter is named, it will also be available by its name.

(https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall)

What I'm doing is converting the data to an object with just the named parameters, like this:

```
cleanAttributes = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(attributes).slice(attributes.length))
```

Notice than `attributes.length` is the amount of positional parameters, so with the slice I'm omitting them. I'd suggest to put that into a function.